# Does Spring's JdbcTemplate close the connection after query timeout?

Tags: java, database, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have set query timeout (getJdbcTemplate().setQueryTimeout(5)) in method with insert statement. What will happen after query timeout, does jdbc template close my connection?

Comment: Probably yes. JdbcTemplate takes care for getting and closing the connections.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In short yes it does close the connection. The long answer it depends.

When you don't have a Spring managed transaction then yes the `JdbcTemplate` will call the `close()` method on the `Connection`. However if there was already a connection available due to Springs transaction management closing the connection will be handled by Springs transaction support, which in turn also will call `close()` on the `Connection`.

The only difference is when the connection is closed but `close()` will be called.

If the connection will be actually closed depends on which `DataSource` is used, in general when using a connection pool the connection will be returned to the pool instead of actually closing the connection.

Comment: is it the `close()` method that's called always called? Because in my program I need Spring to not close the connection so if it's guranteed to be `close()` I can override that method.

Comment: As stated it depends. If you have a specific question please ask a question instead of doing if by comments.

Answer (score 9):

Yes it does.

And if the connection was obtained from connection pool, it won't actually close the connection, rather will send it back to the pool.

Comment: how it is implemented?

Answer (score 6):

No need to close the connection manually. Spring container itself to take care of the operation. Kindly refer to this spring documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#jdbc

Answer (score 0):

By reviewing the source code of JdbcTemplate, there is a method called `execute`, which is the infrastructure of some other query method, such as `queryForObject`, `queryForList` and so on :

```
    @Nullable
    private <T> T execute(StatementCallback<T> action, boolean closeResources) throws DataAccessException {
        Assert.notNull(action, "Callback object must not be null");

        Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(obtainDataSource());
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            applyStatementSettings(stmt);
            T result = action.doInStatement(stmt);
            handleWarnings(stmt);
            return result;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            // Release Connection early, to avoid potential connection pool deadlock
            // in the case when the exception translator hasn't been initialized yet.
            String sql = getSql(action);
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(stmt);
            stmt = null;
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
            con = null;
            throw translateException("StatementCallback", sql, ex);
        }
        finally {
            if (closeResources) {
                JdbcUtils.closeStatement(stmt);
                DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
            }
        }
    }
```

Apparently, when execute get called, the database connection would be release in the finally block , as a result, it`s unnecessary to close the connection after query timeout.